# Issue in magento and wordpress integration[fishpig]

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I have installed wordpress fishpig extension but in setting it ask for database credentials which are `root` and `""`. Unfortunately the password field is required. How to resolve it as it is giving database error.

Comment: Does WP and Magento share same Database ?

Comment: nope I have set a different DB which was using by my previous blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove required entry, go to system.xml inside fishpig module, remove `<validate>required-entry</validate>` inside `<password>` node. This way you can save with blank password.